# Assignment: this expression was expected to have the type unit

Tags: f#

I'm writing some thing really easy, a program that finds all factors of an int. Here is what I have

```
let factor n=
  let ls=[]
  for i=1 to n do
    if i % n =0 then ls = i::ls
  l
```

If I do this then it pops an error This expression was expected to have the type unit. But I tried to put an expression that prints something after if..then.., which is suppose to return type unit, but it still gives the same error. I am lost about this. Can someone help please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to make `ls` into a mutable variable nd assign it with `=`. While this is possible, by using `mutable` [(1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233185.aspx) or `ref` [(2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx) along with `<-` or `:=` assignment operators, this is generally discouraged in the functional world.
A possibly more idiomatic implementation of the naive algorithm could be:

```
let factor n =
    let rec factorLoop curr divs =
        if curr > n then divs
        else
            if n % curr = 0
            then factorLoop (curr+1) (curr::divs)
            else factorLoop (curr+1) divs
    factorLoop 1 [] |> List.rev

> factor 12;;
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 6; 12]
```

Here the main function defines an inner `factorLoop` function that is recursive. Recursion is the way we can avoid many uses of mutable variables in functional languages. The recursive inner function threads along a `curr` variable that is the current divisor to be tested and a list `divs` of currently found divisors. The result includes `1` and `n`. This can be altered respectively by changing the initial value of `curr` and the terminating condition in the first line of `factorLoop`.

It is worth noting that it can all be shrunk down to one line by making use of the F# library:

```
let factor n =
    [1..n] |> List.filter (fun x -> n % x = 0)
```

Here we build a list of values `1..n` and feed them to `List.filter` which applies the given predicate (at the end of the line) to select only divisors on `n`. If `n` is large, however, the temp list will grow very large. We can use a lazily evaluated sequence instead, which won't blow the memory usage:

```
let factor n =
    {1..n} |> Seq.filter (fun x -> n % x = 0) |> Seq.toList
```

Here we filter on a 'lazy' sequence and only convert the (much smaller) sequence of results to a list at the end:

```
> factor 10000000;;
val it : int list =
  [1; 2; 4; 5; 8; 10; 16; 20; 25; 32; ... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` is comparison, not assignment. You want either

```
let factor n =
    let mutable ls = []
    for i = 1 to n do
        if n % i = 0 then ls <- i::ls
    ls
```

or

```
let factor n =
    let ls = ref []
    for i = 1 to n do
        if n % i = 0 then ls := i::(!ls)
    !ls
```

Note, however, that both of these solutions are highly unidiomatic, as there are equally easy immutable solutions to this problem.

Comment: I'd add that these functions don't solve the problem, they are equivalent to `let factor n = [if n >= 0 then yield n]`. The modulo calculation is the wrong way around in both the question and this answer.

Comment: @Vandroiy : This answer is in response to the question that was actually asked, which is regarding the syntax error. The OP did not ask for an effective way to factorize a number. ;-]